# How to skip or ignore execution of tests in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I am writing test in java using TestNG.

I want to skip or ignore a all class methods using conditional inside the class file.

In ruby, I have followed this [How to skip certain tests with Test::Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927405/how-to-skip-certain-tests-with-testunit)

How can I do in java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can throw [`SkipException`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/SkipException.html)'s in your tests if assumptions does not hold, and that mechanism is flexible enough to even mark the test as skipped or failed. [This article](http://blog.xebia.com/conditionally-running-tests-in-testng/) shows how to integrate this approach in a declarative manner in your test suite. Basically you annotate methods with `@Assumes` and have a custom `IInvokedMethodListener`.

Or (I don't encourage this but it's an option), if you can determine what to skip statically, you may generate an XML spec on the fly and run it.

Answer (score 9):

You can ignore test method using the annotation @Test(enabled = false)

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to use an [IAnnotationTransformers](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers) and then disable the test like you can do with `@Test(enabled = false)`.

```
public void transform(ITest annotation, Class testClass,
      Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    if (...determine if the test should be disabled) {
        annotation.setEnable(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking reference from **[this article](https://www.codekru.com/testng/how-to-ignore-test-cases-in-testng)**.

Using the **@Ignore** annotation, you can easily ignore a single test case or all cases inside a class and its subclasses.

- Ignoring a single test case

```
    
    @Test @Ignore
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("Excecuting test1");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
     
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("Excecuting test2");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
     
}
```

The test1() method would be ignored here, and test2() would run.

- Ignoring all cases of a class and its subclasses

```
@Ignore
public class CodekruTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("Excecuting test1");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("Excecuting test2");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

No test case would be executed here. And this not only extends to **CodekruTest** class but its **subclasses** as well.

Please refer to **[this article](https://www.codekru.com/testng/how-to-ignore-test-cases-in-testng)** for more insights on how to ignore the cases in TestNG.