# @BeforeMethod is still executed even if execution is skipped in @BeforeClass

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, testng

I've tests where based on some condition, I skip execution in `@BeforeClass` itself like -

```java
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void beforeClass() {
    if (someCondition) {
            //do something
    } else {
        throw new SkipException("THESE TESTS ARE NOT INTENDED TO EXECUTE: ");
    }       
}

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
    // do something
}
```

But I run tests, skipExecution statement is executed still execution goes in method annotated with `@BeforeMethod` and code under it is executed which results my tests in failure instead of skip status.

Is this known bug in TestNG or issue with TestNG version? I'm using `TestNG 6.9.10` version

Comment: An old post suggests that SkipException works in BeforeMethod but not in other configuration methods - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591712/how-do-i-use-testng-skipexception. You can also skip test methods in runtime by switching the enabled attribute of the Test annotation to false by using the IAnnotationTransformer. - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476985/how-to-skip-or-ignore-execution-of-tests-in-testng (juherr answer)

Comment: Can you please try again using the latest released version of TestNG [currently it is `6.13.1`] ? I am not able to reproduce this issue with it.

Comment: Yes I also cannot reproduce it with testng 6.9.10 when I separately try it out. But it reproduces with our automation framework. Looks somewhere exception is being caught.